# Google Calendar API: organizer name change issue and email notification issue

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I want to integrate google calendar api so that

1. it can show popup and email notification on a specified schedule. when I create the event, it sends an email instantly and that's ok. But I have scheduled another time for email and popup notification(see below) from which I get only popup notification, not getting email for the second time.
2. The developer account is by the email: `a@gmail.com`. So, when inviting others, it shows organizer as `a@gmail.com`.  **To change this, I set organizer object and injected, but not changing anything in the invitation output.**
   Please check my code for further details(I have added only relevant parts of my code, please let me know if anything needed):

```
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2021-01-26T17:22:00+06:00");
 EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(startDateTime)
                .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
        event.setStart(start);
 DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2021-01-26T17:25:00+06:00");
 EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
  event.setEnd(end);

  String[] recurrence = new String[] {"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1"};
            event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));
            EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[] {
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("a@gmail.com"),
                    new EventAttendee().setEmail("b@gmail.com"),
                    
            };
            event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));
    
        EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(10),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
        };
        Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
                .setUseDefault(false)
                .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
        event.setReminders(reminders);
    
        //new fields:
        Event.Organizer organizer= new Event.Organizer().setEmail("b@gmail.com").setDisplayName("myname: test-");
        event.setOrganizer(organizer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You cannot set the event organizer

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource), this is a read-only property.

To transfer the ownership, you need to use the method [Events: move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move). Note that in this case the event will be moved out of the calendar it is currently located into the calendar of the person who is meant be asisgned as the new owner

Comment: thanks for your answer with an explanation. Btw, any insight about my issue no 1? about the email notification I have raised above?

Comment: Can you explain about htis more in detail? How you schedule another time about email and popup notification?

Comment: this way I tried:  `EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[] {
                new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(10),
                new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),` it gives popup correctly but no email is sending 10 mins before the event as I set here.

Comment: you will find the code snippet  in the question

Comment: I think I see now where your problem lies: Overwriting default reminder setting works only for the person who created the event - not for the attendees. Can you confirm theat the person who authenticated when creating the event received a reminder email?

Comment: everybody gets email when the event is created. But as I set 10 mins reminder before the event, nobody is getting that  reminder email , not even the organizer too.

Comment: A notification for event creation and a reminder are different things. For reminders, every user has his own settings - you cannot overwrite the reminders of other users, see [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource): `reminders: Information about the event's reminders for the authenticated user.`,  [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/87149061?hl=en)